# How can I make custom components draggable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Good morning everyone, I'm trying to use the `cdkDrag` directive in an Angular custom component to render it draggable, but without success.
I wrapped it inside a div with the `cdkDrag` directive, but nothing happens:

```html
    <div cdkDrag>
     <my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
    </div>
```

Them i tried to apply `"inline-block"` as style in the `div`, but nothing changes.

```html
    <div cdkDrag style="display: inline-block;">
     <my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
    </div>
```

Someone would be kind to help me to resolve this issue, please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you share stackblitz reproducing the issue?

Comment: please take a look at example implementation https://stackblitz.com/angular/lbvbgxxrkvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `draggable` keyword to make any element draggable.

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div draggable="true">
      <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hi2</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add functionality and make it look much better using JS. I would recommend looking at a tutorial.